# Save XElement to ZipFile via Stream

Tags: c#, xml, xelement, dotnetzip

I'm using a zip file as a repository for xml files and I am trying to save/update files.

I have,

```
protected override void SaveFile()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    var sr = new StreamWriter(ms);
    table.Save(sr); // XElement table is filled elsewhere
    ZipEntry entry = Repository.zip.Entries.FirstOrDefault(z => z.FileName == path);
    if (null == entry)
        Repository.zip.AddEntry(path, ms);
    else
        Repository.zip.UpdateEntry(path, ms);
}
```

But I get an empty xml file as a result.

Repository is opened via a `using()` and it's Dispose calls `SaveFile()` for each xml file that needs saving.  It then calls `zip.Save()` and then `zip.Dispose()`.

Where am I going wrong?

PS I'm using .NET 3.5 so I cannot use the XElement.Save(stream)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After saving into the MemoryStream, the stream position is after the end of the serialised XElement.  My guess is that AddEntry and UpdateEntry do not attempt to reset the stream position, so you will need to do so yourself before calling these APIs:

```
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: Thank you - I don't use stream's very often with .Net, so had forgotten that little caveat.